# How do i to print text without formatting it?

Tags: javascript, html, text

I wan to print text like this in an HTML file, what tags do you suggest?

```
'text \nwithout \nformatting '
```

My js code

```
const editor = document.getElementById('editor')
const previewer = document.getElementById('previewer')

editor.addEventListener('change', () => {
  previewer.textContent = editor.value
})
```

My HTML code

```
  <textarea id="editor" name="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
  <pre id="previewer"></pre>
```

I tried with the deprecated `<plaintext>`, and the `<pre>` tags, i expect to print text without formatting tags like \n and others

Comment: `\n` is not "formatting", it's an escape sequence.

Comment: So you want to preview what is being written in the <textarea> at realtime in another <div>

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear if you want to show newlines as newlines in your previewer, or if you want to remove `\n` (which represents an escaped newline) in the textarea. In any case, this solution does both:

```js
const editor = document.getElementById('editor');
const previewer = document.getElementById('previewer');

editor.addEventListener('input', () => {
   previewer.innerHTML = editor.value.replace(/\\n/g, '');
});;
editor.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
```

```html
<textarea id="editor" name="" cols="50" rows="5">text with
newlines
and escape char \n representing a newline</textarea>
<pre id="previewer"></pre>
```

Notes:

- use `'input'` instead of `'change'` in the event listener, so that an update happens on each keystroke
- `.replace(/\\n/g, '')` on the textarea value strips the escape chars
- use `previewer.innerHTML` so that newlines in the textarea are preserved
- the `.dispatchEvent()` makes sure to show the previewer initially in case you have initial text in the textarea

Comment: The 'input' and the `.dispatchEvent()` are usefully tips, but I want to print line breaks without formatting, the output should show the \n

Comment: Your requirement is not clear. `.replace(/\\n/g, '')` removes `\n` text. Please be more specific. Best you post an example input and expected output.

Comment: @FernandoCastro: If you want to convert text `\n` into an actual newline do this instead: `editor.value.replace(/\\n/g, '\n')`